# converting Two-tailed to One-tailed test

Tags: statistics, education

lets imagine we have a two tailed distribiution for a bunch of data.
right now we want to convert it into one tailed study;our P-value at the first is:

P-value= 0.44

what our p-value is going to be???

I guess answer is 0.88 but textbook says it is going to be in this range:

(0.22 , 0.78)

can anybody explain this for me please.

Comment: Generally, P-value for 2-sided test is twice the P-value for an appropriate one-sided test. Suppose you have $n=100$ observations with $\bar X = 51.27, S =6.546.$ Then t-test of $H_0: \mu=50$ vs $H_a: \mu \ne 50$ has P-val = $ 0.055$ not quite rejecting at 5% level. By contrast, t-test of $H_0:\mu=50$ vs $H_a: \mu > 50$ has P-val=  0.0275.$ significant at 5% level. // This illustrates why it is "cheating" (P-hacking) to change from a 2-sided test to a 1-sided test **after you see the data.**

Comment: In case you're interested, here is R code with results, relevant to above comment. `x = rnorm(100, 52, 7); mean(x); sd(x)` returned $51.27141$ and $6.545754.$ Then `t.test(x, mu=50, alt="greater")$p.val` returned (right-sided) P-value $0.02746866,$ while `t.test(x, mu=50)$p.val` returned (2-sided) P-val  $0.05493733.$ I'll leave it to you to find the t statistic (same for both).